# SQl Server custom function error always returns false (not working) even though the components of it do work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm stuck on a sql server function, pasted below.. I'm trying to return a boolean (bit). I won't bore you with the table schema description and nested udf functionality unless someone would like to see it, since when I test the two values I'm calculating individually, this works fine. I'm getting a value into two local variables, and comparing them. Again individually they work, yet when I run the function, I always get false (I got true in one instance with test data some time back but haven't been able to recreate it for a while). So I wonder if my error is in my assignment statements near the end?

```
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PricingVolDataAvailableToDateProvided
    (@Ticker char,
     @StartDate DATETIME2,
     @NumberOfDaysBack int)
    RETURNS bit
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result bit

    DECLARE @TargetDate DATETIME2
    SET @TargetDate=dbo.TradingDateByStartDate(@NumberOfDaysBack, @StartDate)

    DECLARE @DataPointDateFromTable DATETIME2
    SET @DataPointDateFromTable= (SELECT TOP (1) TradeDate
        FROM (SELECT TOP (@NumberOfDaysBack) TradeDate, Symbol
        FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
        WHERE (Symbol = @Ticker AND TradeDate <= @StartDate)
        ORDER BY TradeDate DESC) AS T2
        ORDER BY TradeDate ASC)

    IF @DataPointDateFromTable = @TargetDate
        SET @Result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 0

    RETURN @Result

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks fine, problem could be on `dbo.TradingDateByStartDate` function, check out if `@DataPointDateFromTable` and `@TargetDate` both have the date and time part of their values, or if you van to compare only date parts, cast them to DATE as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#UsingCastandConvertwithtimedatedatetime2anddatetimeoffset).

Comment: Thanks much.. I'm still working with it though, casts but no luck... is there an equivalent way to PRINT or get some kind of intermediate output or feedback from the sql function as it executes?

Comment: you can print what you want:
`PRINT @DataPointDateFromTable
PRINT @TargetDate`
or
`SELECT @DataPointDateFromTable
SELECT @TargetDate`
just for checking

Comment: I get the error "Invalid use of a side- effecting operator 'PRINT' within a function"..

Comment: Try to run the query in a new query window. But the SELECT statements gonna be fine.